# WebSite template from .Net SDK v2.6 hardcodes the location of some resources

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm tutoring myself on Azure Resource manager and noticed something that looks a bit strange in the WebSite template provided with .net SDK v2.6. Here's the definition of the Microsoft.Web/sites resource:

```
{
            "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
                "displayName": "Website"

            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
                "serverFarm": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
            }
        }
```

Here's the same for a Microsoft.Insights/components resource:

```
{
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
            "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "location": "Central US",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]": "Resource",
                "displayName": "AppInsightsComponent"
            },
            "properties": {
                "applicationId": "[parameters('siteName')]"
            }
        }
```

Why does the Microsoft.Web/sites resource use the siteLocation parameter for the location yet the Microsoft.Insights/components resource hardcodes it as "Central US". is this an oversight or is it simply because that resource is only available in Central-US region?

Answer (score 0):

All of the resources that make up what you think of as "App Insights" are only available in certain locations (central us or east us) - so it's that latter, because it's only available in those regions.